# How to create additional rows or a dataframe based on column values

Tags: r

Here is some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 2), 
                 Amount = c(100, 10, 100),
                 Time = c(0, 0, 24),
                 ADDL = c(5, 0, 1),
                 II = c(24, 24, 24))
```

Using this dataframe I would like to generate the following rows/dataframe, where ADDL is the number of additional rows that should be generated for a given ID, and the II term is the interval in time that each new row should take.

```
#      ID Amount Time 
# 1    1  100    0
# 2    1  100    24
# 3    1  100    48
# 4    1  100    72
# 5    1  100    96
# 6    1  100    120
# 7    2  10     0
# 8    2  100    24
# 9    2  100    48
```

The output dataframe that I would generate will have >350000 rows so an efficient solution is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#fastest option stays away from adding rows using a loop

#add rows function
addRows <- function(x){
  Times <- seq(from = x$Time, to = x$Time + x$ADDL*x$II, by = x$II)
  n <- length(Times)
  x %>% 
    dplyr::slice(rep(row_number(),n)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Time = Times)
}

df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(USUBJID, TIME, ADDL) %>%
  dplyr::group_split() %>%
  purrr::map_dfr( ~ addRows(.))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 3:** use `bind_rows` as shown below.  This is faster than the other two solutions.

```
####  solution 3
  df3 <- setDT(df)
  mydf3 <- setDT(df)
  m1 <- proc.time()
  datalist = list()
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    dlist = list()
    if ( df3$ADDL[i]>0){
      for(j in 1:df3$ADDL[i]){
        dat <- data.table(ID=df3$ID[i],
                          Amount=df3$Amount[i],
                          Time=df3$Time[i]+j*df3$II[i],
                          ADDL=df3$ADDL[i],
                          II=df3$II[i])
        dlist[[j]] <- dat # add it to your list
      }
      datalist[[i]] <- dlist
    }
    
  }
  datalist[[n+1]] <- mydf3
  all_data <- dplyr::bind_rows(datalist)
  all_data[order(ID,Time)]
  m2 <- proc.time()
  print((m2 - m1)[[3]])

>   all_data[order(ID,Time)]
   ID Amount Time ADDL II
1:  1    100    0    5 24
2:  1    100   24    5 24
3:  1    100   48    5 24
4:  1    100   72    5 24
5:  1    100   96    5 24
6:  1    100  120    5 24
7:  2     10    0    0 24
8:  2    100   24    1 24
9:  2    100   48    1 24
```

**OLD ANSWER:**
You can use `lapply` to accomplish this.  The following code gives the expected result on your `df`.  You can drop the variables you don't need from `mydf` dataframe.
**UPDATE:** I have two solutions.  For large amount of data, second solution is better as it uses rbindlist and data.table - both implemented in C and therefore, more efficient.

```
##  Solution 1 in R should suffice for small data frames

mydf <- df
  lapply(1:n, function(i){
    if (df$ADDL[i]>0){
      lapply(1:df$ADDL[i], function(j){
        mydf<<- rbind(mydf,data.frame(ID=df$ID[i],
                                      Amount=df$Amount[i],
                                      Time=df$Time[i]+j*df$II[i],
                                      ADDL=df$ADDL[i],
                                      II=df$II[i]))
      })
    }
  })
  
  mydf[order(mydf$ID,mydf$Time),]
  
  ##  Solution 2 is more efficient for large data - uses data.table and rbindlist
  
  mydf2 <- setDT(df)
  lapply(1:n, function(i){
    if (df$ADDL[i]>0){
      lapply(1:df$ADDL[i], function(j){
        addrow <- data.table(ID=df$ID[i],
                             Amount=df$Amount[i],
                             Time=df$Time[i]+j*df$II[i],
                             ADDL=df$ADDL[i],
                             II=df$II[i])
        mydf2<<- rbindlist(list(mydf2,addrow), use.names=TRUE)
      })
    }
  })
  
  mydf2[order(ID,Time)]
  
  identical(mydf2, setDT(mydf)) 

> identical(mydf2, setDT(mydf))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: The lapply function seems to create multiple output dataframes, the total amount of dataframes generated is the sum of ADDL in the imput dataframe plus one. This is computationally intensive. Is there a way to only create one dataframe with all additional rows?

Comment: Please see the updated solution above which uses `data.table` and  `rbindlist`.

Comment: The data.table solution is stil very slow. I think the issue might be with lapply? The data.table solution still creates multiple output dataframes as the function runs. Is there a way to do this without lapply?

Comment: I think data.table is the way to go.  However, inside lapply I am still using data from dataframe df.  That might be the reason.  let me look at that.  Also, there may be other better options that I am not aware.

Comment: I have posted another solution where `bind_rows` from `dplyr` is used.  This solution 3 is faster than the previous solutions.